# AngularJS and ASP.Net Webapi user start page

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.Net Webapi for my back end but would like to use the AngularJS for the frontend. I did manage to get the OAuth and other security working on my ASP.Net side and on the server side I can easily check the user role using attributes like `[Authorize("Admin Role")]`

My question is now on the AngularJS what is the best way to give a separate start page or the chrome inside which the SPA would run.

- say for e.g. i have the following flow.

  1. user types in my site address "www.mysite.com"
  2. I present with the login screen.
  3. user enters the login information and submits.
  4. Based on the user provide different base path

     - 4.1 : for Admin "www.mysite.com/admin"
     - 4.2 : for Operator "www.mysite.com/operator"
     - 4.3 : for supervisor "www.mysite.com/supervisor"

what i an trying to say is, the views and data is completely different for these kind of users so I can't have one default.htm that will work for all these users and will need different shell to display the views.

I know its easy to do in MVC but not sure how to do it in AngularJS. does someone have a suggestion on how this can be done.

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand the problem, sounds like you would probably want to just separate out the login page and not include it in the SPA, then after the login redirect to the appropriate endpoint and from there have each SPA

Comment: @shaunhusain - yes you are right, I want to direct the  user to the starting point/page based on their login. Unable to understand how it can be done.